# How could I find a row with maximum value of a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like

```
phoneNumber | City      | totalPoints
12345678    | Singapore | 2000
12345679    | Singapore | 3000
23456789    | New York  | 2100
12312312    | New York  | 2200
12312343    | Beijing   | 4000
```

And I want to get result like

```
phoneNumber | City      | totalPoints
12345679    | Singapore | 3000
12312312    | New York  | 2200
12312343    | Beijing   | 4000
```

Just select the row which has the maximun value of totalPoints in each city. How to write the SQL code? (I am using MS SQL Server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql-server :

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by City order by totalpoints desc) from table
)x
where rn=1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! It works but it looks quite odd. I try MAX() and GROUP BY but it seems this cannot work in this case. Any better solutions? Or do I have to change my database design?

Comment: you cannot use a max() if you did then you need to group by ... so in this case this only way left !

Comment: oops.. i missed this part.. why you say "_It works but it looks quite odd._"